# How to write a shell script(any shell languages) that interacts with a program and passes arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, interactive-shell

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
  int number = 0;
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> number ;
  cout << "the number you enter is " << number << endl;

  return 0;}
```

This is my program that takes in an argument and prints it out.

```
#! /bin/bash
number=1
echo "1" | ./a.out #>> result.txt
```

This is my bash script that is trying to pass an argument to the program.

```
1
Please enter a number: the number you enter is 1
```

This is the result.txt. I wanted it more like this:

```
Please enter a number: 1
the number you enter is 1
```

How should I fix it so that the script would pass the argument more like a human does.

And is bash a really good scripting language doing this kind of work or there are other better scripting languages. (google says tcl is better that bash for this kind of interactive program?)

Comment: The program reads from stdin. The script pipes `1` in the stdin so you can't see the same output as run manually. Why would you want that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, if you'd like to pass parameters to your c++ program, you should add argc and argv to your main function.

Your program.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "your number is " << argv[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The shell script (send-arg.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

./program 42
```

Output:

```
./send-arg.sh
your number is 42
```

Comment: This would be the best way to go, but would require editing the source [which could be a very large file] or sometimes the source is not available.